# Передать значение переменной в css через Jquery

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Всем привет, подскажите как передать значение переменной в css

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
    var width_1 = width * 2;
    var width_2 = width * 3;
    var width_3 = width * 4;
    var width_4 = width * 5;
    console.log(width, width_1, width_2, width_3, width_4);

    $(".page-4").click(function(){
        $(".swiper-wrapper").css("transform", "translate3d(-6144px, 0px, 0px)");
    });
    $(".logo-section").click(function(){
        $(".swiper-wrapper").css("transform", "translate3d(width, 0px, 0px)");
    });
```

Нужно width передать в "translate3d(width, 0px, 0px)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте про [шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) и [конкатенацию строк](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA).

1й вариант:

```
$(".swiper-wrapper").css("transform", `translate3d(${width}px, 0px, 0px)`);
```

2й вариант:

```
$(".swiper-wrapper").css("transform", 'translate3d(' + width + 'px, 0px, 0px)');
```

Comment: Спасибо в моем случае нужно еще добавить px после ' + width + '

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Добавил в ответ